# Kitura REST API rate Limiter

Tags: swift, swift3, backend, devops, kitura

I am trying to build REST API's in Swift Language using Kitura. Is there any API Rate-Limiting Middleware in Kitura or Can rate limiting be achieved in any way ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

[KituraLimiter](https://github.com/teechap/kitura-limiter) is a third party implemented rate limiting middleware for Kitura.